# Getting Error Angular Argument 'mainController' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: angularjs

```
    <div ng-app = "myApp" ng-controller = "mainController">

             <table border = "0">
                <tr>
                   <td>Enter first name:</td>
                   <td><input type = "text" ng-model = "student.firstName"></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                   <td>Enter last name: </td>
                   <td><input type = "text" ng-model = "student.lastName"></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                   <td>Name: </td>
                   <td>{{student.fullName()}}</td>
                </tr>

             </table>

          </div>

var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

myApp.controller("mainController", function($scope) {
   $scope.student = {
      firstName: "Mahesh",
      lastName: "Parashar",
      fees:500,

      subjects:[
         {name:'Physics',marks:70},
         {name:'Chemistry',marks:80},
         {name:'Math',marks:65},
         {name:'English',marks:75},
         {name:'Hindi',marks:67}
      ],

      fullName: function() {
         var studentObject;
         studentObject = $scope.student;
         return studentObject.firstName + " " + studentObject.lastName;
      }
   };
});
```

I'm getting a problem with this code it says error "Argument 'mainController' is not a function, got undefined" i can't understand why it is saying. can any one please explain for the same i am very new in angularjs.

Answer (score 0):

It should work according to the information you have provided.

Here is the working [`Plunker`](http://plnkr.co/edit/9O4Sa6H9U4FibQgyrB6A?p=preview) Application

Comment: yeas exactly don't know may be pathing issue i set 
<script src= "/angular/src/mainController.js"></script>
<script src= "/angular/src/myApp.js"></script>

is it ok?

Comment: it depends on your project folder structure.

Comment: check in your network tab, whether the references are loading

Comment: You should load `myApp.js` first. `mainController.js` second. Are you doing that?